# Am I able to dynamically change the captions on a jssor slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I'm working on a site where I have data being pulled in from an external source via js. I want to take this data and plug it into each of the captions and img sources in the slider. I'm using a simple slider with caption that I pulled from the "slider-with-caption.source.html" file provided in the Jssor.

The data coming down are all simple strings. I have run the console to a breakpoint and I do indeed recieve the intended data.

This is where my issue comes in. I have set the content of each of the three slides with a unique id (SEE BELOW). Yet, when I gather my data and subsequently try to insert it into the tag, nothing happens. I've used `$(id).text(data string);` as well as `.html(data string);`

I'll include the code below, please tell me if there's anything in the jssor code that could prevent such an action.

Thanks

EDIT: Noticed that jssor seems to make a copy of all the tags and overlays them, so I tried `$("#annone).each($(this).text(title);` to no avail.

Page HTML:

```
<div id="announcements">
    <div id="slider1_container" class="announcements">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 725px; height: 345px; overflow: hidden;">
            <!-- Slide -->
            <div>
                <img id="annimgone" u="image" src="https://team.gsk.com/sites/chna-aar/SiteAssets/slide1.jpg" />
                <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px;
                    background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                    color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                        <a class="white" style="color:white;" href="#" id="annone">The Change Network</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <div>
                <img id="annimgtwo" u="image" src="https://team.gsk.com/sites/chna-aar/SiteAssets/slide2.jpg" />
                <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px; ">
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px;
                    background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px;
                    color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                        <a class="white" style="color:white;" href="#" id="anntwo">Express Learning</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <div>
                <img id="annimgthree" u="image" src="https://team.gsk.com/sites/chna-aar/SiteAssets/slide3.jpg" />
                <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px; ">
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px; background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 725px; height: 50px; color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                        <a class="white" style="color:white;" href="#" id="annthree">Opport-Tuesdays</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">javascript carousel</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var siteURL = '/sites/chna-aar/'

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
            var site = clientContext.get_web();
            var list = site.get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

            var query = '<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="Title" /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="False" /></OrderBy></Query>'

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);

            var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.load(items);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

                while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var item = enumerator.get_current();
                    var title = '';
                    title = item.get_item('Title');

                    $("#annone").text(title);
                    //Alternative - $("#annone").html(title);
                }
            }, function () { });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks correct, not sure what's the problem.

But it would be better if you initialize jssor slider after you altered all captions.

```
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var item = enumerator.get_current();
                var title = '';
                title = item.get_item('Title');

                $("#annone").text(title);
                //Alternative - $("#annone").html(title);
            }

            //initialize jssor slider when you get all content ready
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
        }, function () { });
```